# Hide a specific part of geometry in Blender sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting

Is there any way to hide a specific part of geometry in Blender sculpting mode like Zbrush?

Here is an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select some faces in *Edit* mode, **hide** them (<kbd>H</kbd>), and they will remain hidden in *Sculpt* mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide)

You also have a ***Box Hide*** brush in *Sculpt* mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide). I'm not sure there's any other way to hide when in *Sculpt* mode but I may be wrong:

[image]

You also have a ***Mask*** brush (shortcut <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to erase parts of the mask, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to clear), the masked part is not hidden but can't be sculpted. And you have a *Box Mask* (and *Lasso Mask* and *Line Mask* in the submenu):

[image]

You also have ***Face Sets*** but they work a bit differently than masks.
And of course <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> for ***Clipping Borders***, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to exit, to only make a part of your scene visible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution sorry for not explaining it properly. it really helped me a lot thank you so much!